# recursive directory listing using powershell

Tags: powershell

I’m trying to list every file, including dll, exe, driver list, etc along with their **properties** on my windows system using PowerShell.

The following gives me desired list in console

```
 PS C:\Windows> Get-ChildItem c:\windows -include *.dll -recurse | foreach-object { "{0}" -f [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($_) }
```

Now, I'm trying to pipe this output, nicely formatted into a csv file, so I use this snippet

```
 PS C:\Windows> Get-ChildItem c:\windows -include *.dll -recurse | foreach-object { "{0}" -f [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($_) } | Export-CSV C:\4_may_2.csv
```

which in turn gives out this error:

```
 Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\windows\CSC\v2.0.6'
```

I'm denied, everytime I try, it fails, can't understand where I'm failing.

Comment: Are you running PowerShell as administrator? Writing to the root of C:\ or in to the \Windows directory is typically restricted. Try writing to your \documents folder instead.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an OS level permissions issue.

Writing to the root of `C:\` or in to the `\Windows` directory is typically restricted so you either need to run PowerShell as Administrator or create the output file in an alternative (non-restricted) location such as your `\documents` folder.